# Using CxxTest with Travis-CI

Tags: build, continuous-integration, apt, travis-ci, cxxtest

Here is the portion of my `.travis.yml` that handles the dependency installation for my wxWidgets/CxxTest project:

```
install:
  - echo | sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dhart/ppa
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq libwxgtk2.8 cxxtest
env: CXXTEST=/usr/include
```

Everything installs fine, and the project builds successfully, but when it comes time to call `cxxtestgen`, it goes kaput.

```
cxxtestgen: Command not found
```

How do I install CxxTest onto Travis-CI while making the `cxxtestgen` command accessible?

Here is my github project: https://github.com/gbchaosmaster/nds-toolkit

Comment: mention your github project here, so others can fork to check it more easily

Comment: @larrycai https://github.com/gbchaosmaster/nds-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -qq cxxtest
Unable to locate package cxxtest
```

`cxxtest` is not in trusted archive in ubuntu 12.04 (precise), which is used in travis-ci now (2012.11), it can't be installed there directly using command `apt-get install`

See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cxxtest

Using either Ubuntu PPA or installation of `cxxtest` itself (like build from source)

Beside the answer, below is the way to debug in general

```
# .travis-ci.yml
- sudo apt-get install -qq cxxtest
env: CXXTEST=/usr/include

# Test build success and unit test passing.
script:
  - dpkg -L cxxtest
  - echo $PATH
  - cxxtestgen
```